# I am yielding data in while scraping,I need the scraped data in csv file in orderde fields

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am yielding data but when I download csv file the fields/headers wanted to be in a specified order,how should I bring the fields in csv file in ordered format

```
  data = {
                        "last_name": last_name,

                        "mixed": mixed,
                        "singles": singles,

                        "city": city,
                        "state": state,
                     }
```

Comment: Are you using `csv.DictWriter` ?

Comment: Post what you have tried. The python script that you mentioned. And please format your code.

Comment: You should use a [`csv.DictWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). The `fieldnames` parameter provides the order of the columns that will be used when writing a dictionary as a row using the `.writerow()` method.

Comment: sample can u tell me

Comment: Check out the link, there's one example right under the heading.